# JFreeChart - ChartFactory.createXYStepChart with to-concept

Tags: java, charts, jfreechart

By default **XYStepChart** in **JFreeChart** implements **"from concept"** what means that if we have following data: (1,4), (2,5) the step chart is drawn like this:

1. horizontal line from x=1 to x=2 with y=4
2. vertical line in x=2 (to value y=5).

I would like to draw those data on the step chart with **"to concept"** what means:

1. horizontal line from x=0 to x=1 with y=4
2. vertical line in x=1 (to value y=5)
3. horizontal line from x=1 to x=2 with y=5

Does JFreeChart support such concept by default or I would have to implement it by myself (by modyfying input data for example)?

Maybe you know another Java charting library which supports mentioned to concept?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get close to what you are looking for by using the [setStepPoint()](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/renderer/xy/XYStepRenderer.html#setStepPoint%28double%29) method in the [XYStepRenderer](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/renderer/xy/XYStepRenderer.html) class.  This attribute is a value in the range from 0.0 to 1.0, with the default being 1.0.  When making the transition between two points (x0, y0) and (x1, y1), at some point a vertical move needs to be made from y0 to y1.  The stepPoint determines where, in the range from x0 to x1, the vertical transition will be made.  If stepPoint == 1.0 (the default), the vertical transition is made at x1.  If stepPoint == 0.0, the vertical transition is made at x0.  If stepPoint is some value in between (say 0.5) then the vertical transition is made at that fractional point along the range (x0, x1).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Btw you could add this to your documentation. Do you know maybe if there is a possibility to set a different renderer (I mean for example with diffrerent colour) for some part of the step chart. I mean in the case that the whole step diagram is red but we would like to have the line between x=2,3 to x=3,6 in blue. I can create another question for it if you prefer so. Thanks anyway.

Comment: I updated the docs for the next release, thanks for the feedback.  Regarding changing the color within the series, JFreeChart always calls the getItemPaint() method in the renderer to get the color for each data point...by default this method returns the same color for the whole series.  But you could subclass the renderer and override it to return different colors for different items in a single series (confusing though if the chart has a legend).  Another alternative, without modifying JFreeChart, would be to use 2 data series (put the data that should be in blue in the second series).

Comment: Ok it would be exactly what I need.

Comment: One more question. Is it possible to set similar stepPoint also for XYStepAreaRenderer? I have the use case in which I have to draw the data once as stepped line and then the same as stepped chart. But i don't see the possibility to set up step point for areas?!